# Hausdorff space with finite derived set is normal

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space with $A:=\{x\in X:x \hbox{ is not an isolated point}\}$ finite. Then the space $X$ is normal.
I was trying to take two disjoint closed sets but I can't find the disjoint open sets that separate this closed sets. I was trying to think $A$ as closed, because any finite set in a HAusdorff space is closed.

Any help will be appreciated.